# War File size is 110MB: Package Excludes are not working

Tags: maven, extjs, extjs4

I am building a war file.  The application uses Spring, Hibernate, and EXTJS.  When I build the war file in maven all the things I asked to be excluded is making it into the war file.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.build.finalName}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/build/temp/${sencha.env}/TTT}</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Readme.md</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <packagingExcludes>.sencha/**,app/**,build/**,ext/**,overrides/**,packages/**,sass/**,bootstrap.css,bootstrap.js,bootstrap.json,build.xml,Readme.md</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain that i was using my IDE and the pom.xml to generate and deploy my war file.  The process was copying the entire workspace in the war.  This was like 110MB.

In an effort to isolate the issue I ran maven from the command line (CLI).  What I discovered was the IDE or a plugin was not working.  Running maven using the CLI generate a 14.4MB war.

[image]